# Retrieve IP Address of the Default Printer Driver in UWP

Tags: printing, uwp, driver, ip-address

We have a requirement to get the printer IP Address configured in the default printer driver in Control Panel in our UWP app.

I was able to retrieve the "**System.DeviceInterface.PrinterPortName**" by fetching interface class GUID and passing this above property for retrieval.

**But I couldn't get "System.Devices.IpAddress" similarly.** 
Code pasted below for PortName.

I badly need the IP address as the port name is user's choice and could be modified to any name removing the IP address.

Kindly help sharing working code to retrieve the IP Address using above property or any other way in UWP app.

Below is Working Code for Port Name, Kindly help to fetch IP Address of the same port similarly.

```
        string aqsFilter = "System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{0ecef634-6ef0-472a-8085-5ad023ecbccd}\"";

        string[] propertiesToRetrieve = new string[] { "System.DeviceInterface.PrinterPortName"};

        DeviceInformationCollection deviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqsFilter, propertiesToRetrieve);

        foreach (DeviceInformation deviceInfo in deviceInfoCollection)
        {
            if (deviceInfo.IsDefault == true)
            {
                string strPortName = (string)deviceInfo.Properties["System.DeviceInterface.PrinterPortName"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPortName))
                {
                    strPortName = await ParsePortName(strPortName);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPortName))
                    {
                        _strIPAddress = strPortName;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seems not all default printer has the IP Address. For example, if Windows manage your default printer then it will choose the last printer you used. How did you connect your printer? From a network location?

Comment: Here in this case the default printer has IP address and in the default printer driver same IP address is configured in a port for which I was able to fetch the portname using above code.
Printer is in local network, both my PC and printer in same subnet.

Kindly help in how to fetch IP Address of the same port similar to portname

Comment: Kindly share any suggestions/code that solves my problem asap, It is very critical for me..

Comment: Any expertise available in this area, kindly provide suggestions/solution.

Comment: Kindly help any one with this issue. Is there anyone who has this expertise and can answer me, please...

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Please provide any solution or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not endorsed because the IP address can change and so it is unreliable.**

That being said, if your printer is installed using wsd, it is technically supported 
E.g.,
DEVPKEY_PNPX_IpAddress DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING_LIST 32 "10.137.192.202"
**But there is no way to reliably use this without a lot of various scenario checks since the IP address may change.**

Furthermore, looking at this example, you are not hitting the DAF providers but looking for devices. You are using 0ecef634-6ef0-472a-8085-5ad023ecbccd which is the printer class guid. It also does not look like IP address is propagated in the PnP Explorer property bag so the IP address is not accessible.

Comment: With the above code or approach I understand that it is not accessible. as per your comments.
So is there any other way in UWP to achieve my scenario to fetch IP Address configured for default driver???

Comment: As mentioned, there is no reliable way to fetch IP address without a lot of various scenario checks since the IP address may change. It is strongly discouraged, but you may be able to query the printer you are looking for, grab the container ID, and then do an Aep query for a device with that container id and pull the IP address out of this. But keep in mind, that this is unreliable.